# A field K with an archimedean valuation is ismorphic to a subfield of C and is equivalent to the absolut ordinary valuation in C

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, valuation-theory

I've found this statement in the book I'm using for my final project. I don't seem to be able to find a demonstration for it. The closest I've found is in the book *Local Fields* by J.W.S. Cassels, but it's demonstrated for complete fields with an archimedean valuation, and not all fields.

The original Theorem is in french:

[image]

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general case follows immediately from the complete case, by taking the completion.  If $K$ is a an archimedean valued field, then its completion is a complete archimedean valued field, which is then isomorphic (as a valued field) to a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.  Since $K$ embeds in its completion, the same is true of $K$.